# Split string on spaces except for in quotes, but include incomplete quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to split a string in JS on spaces except when the space is in a quote.   However, an incomplete quote should be maintained.  I'm not skilled in regex wizardry, and have been using the below regex:

```
var list = text.match(/[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/g)
```

However, if I provide input like `sdfj "sdfjjk` this will become `["sdfj","sdfjjk"]` rather than `["sdfj",""sdfjjk"]`.

Comment: Maybe [`var re = /\S+|"([^"]*)"/g;`](https://jsfiddle.net/8bxep40n/1/)?

Comment: You are a god.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think this works on input of `"abc def"`, because it returns `[""abc", "def""]`.

Comment: @torazaburo: That regex  does not handle all cases, just the one shown in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var re = /"([^"]*)"|\S+/g;
```

By using `\S` (=`[^\s]`) we just drop the `"` from the negated character class.
By placing the `"([^"]*)"` pattern before `\S+`, we make sure substrings in quotes are not torn if they come before. This should work if the string contains well-paired quoted substrings and the last is unpaired.

Demo:

```js
var re = /"([^"]*)"|\S+/g; 
var str = 'sdfj "sdfjjk';
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(str.match(re));
```

Note that to get the captured texts in-between quotes, you will need to use `RegExp#exec` in a loop (as `String#match` "drops" submatches).

## UPDATE

No idea what downvoter thought when downvoting, but let me guess. The quotes are usually used around word characters. If there is a "wild" quote, it is still a quote right before/after a word.

So, we can utilize word boundaries like this:

```
"\b[^"]*\b"|\S+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP5gS8/1).

Here, `"\b[^"]*\b"` matches a `"` that is followed by a word character, then matches zero or more characters other than `"` and then is followed with a `"` that is preceded with a word character.

Moving further in this direction, we can make it as far as:

```
\B"\b[^"\n]*\b"\B|\S+
```

With `\B"` we require that `"` should be preceded with a non-word character, and `"\B` should be followed with a non-word character.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP5gS8/2)

**A lot depends on what specific issue you have with your specific input!**

Comment: I tried this on `text = 'abc "def ghi" lmn "opq'`. It returns `["abc", ""def", "ghi"", "lmn", ""opq"]`.

Comment: @torazaburo: I added more explanation. It will be rather difficult to account for all cases. See [this demo with your test strings](https://regex101.com/r/hQ0lU1/1)

Comment: @nanogru: If the answer happens to fail to work with your input, please let me know. I described when it should work in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
text.match(/".*?"|[^\s]+/g).map(s => s.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1"))
```

This repeatedly finds either properly quoted substrings (first), OR other sequences of non-whitespace. The `map` part is to remove the quotes around the quoted substrings.

```
> text = 'abc "def ghi" lmn "opq'
< ["abc", "def ghi", "lmn", ""opq"]
```