# Regular Express - Pattern matching

Tags: regex

How to include everything after /blog but shouldn't include words like wp-content and wp-includes?

Currently showing all using regex:

```
^/blog/*
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
^/blog/(!(wp-content&&wp-includes))*
```

Urls:

```
example.com/blog/content (should include)
example.com/blog/page/2 (should include)
example.com/blog/wp-content/ (shouldn't include)
example.com/blog/wp-includes/ (shouldn't include)
```

Comment: You posted a story, not a question.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about, but going to guess `^/blog/(.(?!wp-content|wp-includes))*$` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Haha, my bad. I have edited my question. Have a look and let me know if you can answer it.

Comment: @Chopra, take a look at my comment and see if it answers your question.

Comment: @ndn I think it is, post it as an answer with maybe an explanation about lookarounds :)

Comment: Language or app? Because a 'not' pattern is usually easier to implement as a separate condition. Also - your first isn't a regex.

Comment: @Sobrique The first *is* a valid regex, why not?

Comment: `/*` means it matches `/blog`, `/blog/` and `/blog///////////` - I very much doubt that's what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to do a `glob` where that syntax would work.

Comment: @ndn it doesn't work on this http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/

Comment: @ndn Your negative lookahead is applied *after* the first arbitrary character, which means you allow the disallowed strings immediately after `blog/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex

```
^/blog/*
```

Means *a string, starting with `/blog` that has **zero or more** forward slashes after that*. I'm guessing you meant just

```
^/blog
```

or

```
^/blog/.*$
```

---

As for how to exclude those two words:

```
^/blog(.(?!wp-content|wp-includes))*$
```

The idea is to advance one character at a time (`.`), checking that `wp-content` or `wp-includes` doesn't follow after that using [negative lookahead (`(?!)`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) til the end of the string (`$`).

---

If you want to ensure the slash after `blog` is there without repeating the regex, you can put the negative lookahead first and then start matching characters:

```
^/blog/(?!.*(wp-content|wp-includes)).*$
```

This first ensures that there is no `wp-content` or `wp-includes` after any amout of characters (`.*`) and then continues matching.

Comment: I'll be glad to hear @downvoter explanation as well so we can all learn from mistakes.

Comment: ^/blog/(?!.*(wp-content|wp-includes)).*$ - This one worked. Thanks @ndn

Comment: @ndn Downvoters [are keeping silent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34964458/3832970) today.

Comment: @Chopra why the hell are you using wrong examples?? there is no way `^/blog...anything` can possibly work for the examples in your question :( (FTR, I have no idea why this answer was downvoted, just not sure why accepted to the question as currently stated)

Comment: @Aprillion, how do you know that the example is wrong and the server isn't just getting stripped like it would in httpd rewriterule or something?

Comment: @Chopra: Apart from this solution you might also wanna check `.htaccess` file and restrict directory traversing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use negative lookahead like this:

```
/blog(/(?!wp-content|wp-includes).*)
```

if the semantics of the match is "inside a url", then you most likely only want to match non-whitespace characters:

```
/blog(/(?!wp-content|wp-includes)\S*)
```

and if there are more than the 2 "wp-" examples:

```
/blog(/(?!wp-)\S*)
```

..not using `^` because your examples do not match at the beginning of the string

https://regex101.com/r/gP4eZ7